# Android app use photo for friends list

Tags: android, list, photo

I am trying to create a friends list in an android app where I would like to use a photo from my photo album on my phone as a photo that other people can see. I am not sure how to approach this but I know how to create a friends list. I just don't know how to make the connection of adding a photo for others to see.

Currently using eclipse to program my android apps.

Comment: Give more detail about what you what to do. Do you want a list of contact with [image][text] ?